# how to fix div position

Tags: html, css

would you see guys. my each image bottom have one caption bar with title. but that not same height for all box. all i want it will same height in all box and if you rollover then you will see that box slideup that's fine. also it will resposive. i am still trying but can not figureout it. would you guess see where i mistake. i just want to make that perfect. even if you any other css or js like that with responsive support then post here please.

thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/BAVXH/

bellow is css for caption

```
.box {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F00;
}
.box img {
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box .caption {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        position: absolute;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        transition: all 300ms ease-out;
        left: 0;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 2%;
        top: 92%;
        height:96%;
    }
    .box:hover .caption {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-89%);
        -o-transform: translateY(-89%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-89%);
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(-89%);
    }
```

Comment: I am still not getting your point??.

Comment: Problem is with using percentage (%), if you use `px` you can have same `height` for `.caption`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this with jQuery and calculate the top for each caption.

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
var h = $('.col-'+i).height();
$('.col-'+i).find(".caption").css("top",h-25 + "px");
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: Or you can put it in a function an call it every time mouseleaves the image and calculate only the specific caption's top.

Answer (score 0):

put height in px not in % like

```
.box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2%;
    top: 92%;
    height:100px;
}
```